# Cross site scripting flaw while writing HTTP response in Servlet(downloading excel file)

Tags: java, xss, owasp, esapi, veracode

The below code is prone to cross site scripting attack which has been reported by veracode scan :

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
    {

        byte[] inputBytes = request.getParameter("input").getBytes();
        String name = request.getParameter("filename") == null?"excelReport":request.getParameter("filename").toString();
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setContentLength(inputBytes.length);
        response.addHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+name+".xls");
        try {
            response.getOutputStream().write(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.length);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I understand the line of code - `response.getOutputStream().write(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.length);` is prone for XSS attack.

How to fix XSS(Cross site scripting) flaw here? Is there any ESAPI library that can be used on byte[] array to fix the XSS flaw?

Comment: Please share the view code.  Is difficult to answer without all the pieces

Comment: @avgvsts There is nothing in the view layer. The above servlet code is written for facilitating excel download.

Comment: The problem here is that you just copy back the "input" parameter you got with the request.

Comment: @Henry. I agree with you. Can you please tell me how to sanitize this input bytes against XSS attack?

Comment: I guess, your method is just a stub as it does not make much sense to just send back the input. I propose you get your business logic complete first. The warning may then get away.

Comment: @Henry. This code is not a stub. The input file is a JSP which contains tabular data. The contents of this table is being sent in the request body to the servlet(HTTP POST method). The tabular content is then read in the servlet via request.getParameter("input"). The object is to provide user an option to download/export the tabular data in UI to excel.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that need to happen for a good defense-in-depth approach to preventing XSS.

1. Output Encoding
2. Input validation

You have several security issues with your code, not just XSS.  But to finish on your primary question, OWASP's ESAPI has an encoder, and there's also the ESAPI Encoder project.   The correct approach would be to use an encoder as close to when you hand it off to an interpreter.  Since you're using a JSP, you will want to encode any output you display to users in order to keep them safe.

Your other issues:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        //Did we get the correct file?  
        byte[] inputBytes = request.getParameter("input").getBytes();
        //Validation against legal characters in the filename?
        String name = request.getParameter("filename") == null?"excelReport":request.getParameter("filename").toString();
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setContentLength(inputBytes.length);
        //This is the line that's immediately triggering your problem.  The attacker controls that filename and you've done nothing to check it!  
        //If you encoded here you MIGHT be fine!  
        response.addHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+name+".xls");
        try {
            response.getOutputStream().write(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.length);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

If you want to understand this vulnerability, use a tool like OWASP's ZAP and modify the filename parameter to a value like `<script>alert(1);</script>` and you'll see the exploit in action.

As to the file itself, ESAPI only provides the means to check against a whitelist of file extensions, it's not very good but file validation is actually fairly difficult to do correctly.  So no, there is no method to validate your file bytes.